How to convert structured nested data to XML which can be opened in Excel
I have python data which can be represented in a pandas DataFrame that looks somewhat like this:
sheet1_df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Name": ["Alice", "Bob"],
    "Age": [30, 25]
})

sheet2_df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Product": ["Laptop", "Phone"],
    "Price": [1000, 500]
})

dataframes_dict = {
    "Sheet1": sheet1_df,
    "Sheet2": sheet2_df,
}

NOTE: I do not need to use pandas, this was only as an example.
How could I convert it into an XML file that could be viewed within Excel with multiple sheets? Excel comes with the ability to save a .xlsx file as a .xml file naturally, but I'd like to take care of the conversion within Python. The example output would look like this:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
    xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
    xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
    xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
    xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
    <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1">
        <Table>
            <Row>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Name</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Age</Data>
                </Cell>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Alice</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="Number">30</Data>
                </Cell>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Bob</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="Number">25</Data>
                </Cell>
            </Row>
        </Table>
    </Worksheet>
    <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet2">
        <Table>
            <Row>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Product</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Price</Data>
                </Cell>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Laptop</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="Number">1000</Data>
                </Cell>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="String">Phone</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <Data ss:Type="Number">500</Data>
                </Cell>
            </Row>
        </Table>
    </Worksheet>
</Workbook>

BONUS: It would also be great to know how to take care of formatting and sizing columns and rows appropriately when viewed in excel.

Here's a method that uses elementary string operations to output such a file:
from datetime import datetime
from math import isnan
from typing import Literal

from pandas import DataFrame, Index, Series

def get_xml_from_df_dict(
    df_dict: dict[str, DataFrame],
) -> BytesIO:
    lines = []
    lines.append('<?xml version="1.0"?>')
    lines.append('<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>')
    lines.append('<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"')
    lines.append('    xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"')
    lines.append('    xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"')
    lines.append('    xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"')
    lines.append('    xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">"')

    for sheet_name, df in df_dict.items():
        lines.append(df_to_table(sheet_name, df))

    lines.append("</Workbook>")

    xml = "\n".join(lines)
    return BytesIO(str.encode(xml))


def df_to_table(sheet_name: str, df: DataFrame) -> str:
    lines = [f'\n    <Worksheet ss:Name="{sheet_name}">']
    lines.append("        <Table>")

    lines.append(series_to_row(df.columns))
    for _, row in df.iterrows():
        lines.append(series_to_row(row))

    lines.append("        </Table>")
    lines.append("    </Worksheet>")

    return "\n".join(lines)


def series_to_row(row: Series | Index) -> str:
    lines = ["\n             <Row>"]
    for value in row:
        lines.append(value_to_cell(value))
    lines.append("            </Row>")
    return "\n".join(lines)


def value_to_cell(value: datetime | int | float | str) -> str:
    if value_is_null(value):
        return '                <Cell><Data ss:Type="String"></Data></Cell>'

    value_type = value_to_type(value)
    if isinstance(value, datetime):
        return f'                <Cell><Data ss:Type="{value_type}">{value.strftime(r"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")}</Data></Cell>'
    return f'                <Cell><Data ss:Type="{value_type}">{value}</Data></Cell>'


def value_is_null(value: datetime | int | float | str) -> bool:
    if isinstance(value, (datetime, str)):
        return False
    if isinstance(value, (int, float)):
        return isnan(value)


def value_to_type(value: datetime | int | float | str) -> Literal["String", "Number"]:
    return "Number" if isinstance(value, (int, float)) else "String"

